# Android Display image in progress bar instead of color

Tags: android, image, android-progressbar

[Progress bar image](http://s8.postimg.org/ezbdf147p/stack_1.jpg)

Hello cane someone help me please. I have bean trying for more than four hours to accomplish the following. I want  the  progress bar to display an image  instead to display a color.
I haven't found any tutorial about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Paint` object with bitmap shader:

```
paintImage = new Paint();
paintImage.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP));
```

and then draw with it like as you draw with usual color paint:

```
canvas.drawRect(new Rect(...), paintImage);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can you give an example pleas I really didn't understand what you are doing exactly.
Are you suggesting that I read the pixels from the bitmap then add them to the canvas one at a time?

Comment: if you provide pictures how this progress bar should look at start, end and some intermediate point, maybe I could help. You question is not very clear so far